# Contribute a Module in joomla

Tags: joomla1.7

I have finished a module in joomla name mod_widget now i want to deploy on joomla website to another users.
User download and use it.How can i upload this Please someone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a JED account. Register for that [here](http://extensions.joomla.org). Then browse until you reach your perfect category to which you need to upload. After reaching you will find a button to submit your own extension. read more about it [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/help2?showall=1) under Submitting an extension.